# BrowserComponent Javascript Engine

Tags: codenameone

I'm rewriting my interface to the javascript engine available in the BrowserComponent but I'm a bit confused.  I used to make java methods and objects available to the javascript scripts as below but I admit I can't find a way to do the same now.

Hope you can help.

E.

Object sample:

```
    JSObject obj = (JSObject) ctx.get("{}");
    if (data != null) {
        for (String key : data.keySet()) {
            obj.set(key, data.get(key));
        }
    }
    ctx.set("window.data", obj);
```

Method sample:

```js
JSObject devnull = (JSObject) ctx.get("{}");
devnull.set("devnull", new JSFunction() {
    @Override
    public void apply(JSObject self, Object[] args) {
        //How about the args?
    }
});
ctx.set("window.devnull", devnull);
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole `JSObject` package has been deprecated for a while. You should use [this](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/BrowserComponent.html#createJSProxy-java.lang.String-) instead. See [this post](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-async-java-javascript-interop-api.html) which discusses the API. You can also find information about that API in the [developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/developer-guide.html).

Comment: Hello Shai, tx for the answer.  Quick question still, is the following allowed for instance?
JSProxy window = bc.createJSProxy("window");
window.setAndWait("data", new HashMap<String, Object>(data));

Comment: I don't see why not?